# cannot change SELinux context even as root?

Tags: linux, bash, selinux

I have a binary file "gs" which isn't executing on this server like it is on all other servers. I noticed its permissions end with a dot '.' and as I understand it, that is SELniux in action...

I need to get this off my file, and after trying the suggested command on a linux forum I'm not allowed to change my own file:

```
[root@server24 bin]# setfattr -h -x security.selinux gs
setfattr: gs: Permission denied
[root@server24 bin]# whoami
root
```

Here are the perms:

```
[root@siteserver24 bin]# ls -latrh gs
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9.4K Nov 11 15:43 gs
```

Comment: might want to add the selinux tag to get appropriate people in here

Comment: extended attributes != SELinux

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Although `getfattr -h -n security.selinux gs` returned `security.selinux="system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0"`, you can't use `setfattr` to remove the `selinux context`. This extended attribute was created by selinux. You have to use `chcon` to change `selinux context` of a file.